# detect listItem from button click

Tags: android, listview, button, onclick, position

I have a listView with an adapter. Every item has two buttons, and i need to detect from which listItem the button was pressed.
Here is my code:

```
List<String> mList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(mNames));
        ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_item_friends_new,
                R.id.friends_new_name,
                mList
        ){
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
                Button button1 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_2);

                button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "user #" + position + " was added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "user #" + position + " was removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                return view;
            }
        };
```

It shows me this error:

```
Error:(67, 47) error: local variable position is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final.
```

Please help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could workaround it when you use a helping variable, which is final and has as value the value of the `position` parameter of the `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method. Try with something like this:

```
final int selectedPosition = position;
```

This line comes before the following line `button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()` and then where you need the current position, use the `selectedPosition` variable instead of the `position` variable which is not final

Comment: Hi again! I need your advice, if you would be so kind :)
 How can i correct get Cursor for clicked button for current listItem?

here is detailed question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160352/how-to-get-getitematposition-in-getview