# How to get getItemAtPosition in getView?

Tags: android, cursor, android-cursoradapter, getview

I have `ImageView` with listItems from db, and every list items have two `Buttons` (add friend/rejectFriend).
I am also using `CursorAdapter`, and inside of my adapter I have  `getView()` method to set listeners and catch clicks on current item `Button`.

and here the question:
I need to get some data from db for current item, when i catch click on item `Button` (add friend for example). so with help of `getView()` parameters I can get the position of `ListView` item, but how from `getView()` correct call cursor and `getItemAtPosition` ?

here is my `getView()` method from adapter class:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        View view =  super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        Button mAcceptNewFriend = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_itemFriendsAddNew_accept);
            Button mRejectNewFriend = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_itemFriendsAddNew_reject);

            mRejectNewFriend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "user #" + position + " was removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
            mAcceptNewFriend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int friendId = mCursor.getInt(FriendsFragment.F_FRIEND_ID);
                }
            });
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Is your parent view a listView with items that have two buttons or I understood your question wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Second possible solution:**

Тry with the following solution: adding a cursor with the constructor of your `CoursorAdapter` and then use `cursor.moveToPosition(position)` in the `getView()` method: [Get correct cursor in CustomCursor Adapater getView()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553389/get-correct-cursor-in-customcursor-adapater-getview)

Answer (score 0):

When your parent view is a listView, you could try to add in the class where is your ListView filled in a method for the listItemClick and to get in it the cursor for example like this:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long ida) {
   super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, ida);

   Cursor mycursor = (Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position); //I'm not sure for the getListView() part and I think that it could be (Cursor)l.getItemAtPosition(position); Please try with both suggestions if the first doesn't work for you
   Toast.makeText(mActivity, "mycursor.getString(1) " + mycursor.getString(1) +"   ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: hm, cannot resolve onListItemClick in my fragment...
can you please give more explicit answer how to do this stuff?

Comment: try to add in your class definition the following implementation: `implements OnItemClickListener`

Comment: i have already implemented OnItemClickListener, but it provides not onListItemClick, but onItemClick...
and when I am pressing button on listItem, onItemClick listener doesnot work....

Comment: Try to set the OnListItemClickListener like this for example: `listview.setOnItemClickListener(new onItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(){
        //here comes the code for the cursor from above
    }
});` 
and in the Cursor line change getListView() with listView (the variable with your listView)

Comment: when i am calling new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() it calls onItemClick, but not onListItemClick, and if i am trying to overwrite it - cannot resolve method

Comment: hmmm then try with the onItemClick method like this for example: `@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
     Cursor tmpCursor = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82481/discussion-between-andriy-antonov-and-gabriella-angelova).